# Directory structure for project with Dockerfile, Jekinsfile, Kubernetes deployment yaml, pip requirements.txt, and test scripts?

Tags: docker, jenkins, pip, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

Would the following directory structure work?

The goal is to have Jenkins trigger off GitHub commits and run Multi-branch Pipelines that build and test containers. (I have everything running on Kubernetes, including Jenkins)

```
/project
  .git
  README.md
  Jenkinsfile
  /docker_image_1
    Dockerfile
    app1.py
    requirements.txt
    /unit_tests
      unit_test1.py
      unit_test2.py
  /docker_image_2
    Dockerfile
    app2.py
    requirements.txt
    /unit_tests
      unit_test1.py
      unit_test2.py
  /k8s
    /dev
      deployment.yaml
    /production
      deployment.yaml
  /component_tests
    component_tests.py
```

1. Is the k8s folder that has the deployment.yamls in the right place?
2. Are the test folders in good locations? The tests in "component_tests" will ideally be doing more end-to-end integrated testing that involve multiple containers
3. I see a lot of repos have Jenkins file and Dockerfile in the same directory level. What are the pros and cons of that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is really left much to your preference.
In our projects we tend to split services into separate repositories not subfolders, but we also had a case where we had a bunch of Scala microserviced managed in similar way (although dockers were built with sbt plugin for docker)

One big advice I would give you is that in the long run managing your kubernetes manifests like that might become serious pain in the back. I went through this, and my suggestion is to use `helm` charts from day one.

I assume that your "component_tests" are end-to-end tests. Other then naming I see no problem with that. For cases where we test solutions that span multiple repos we keep them in a separate repo as well though.

Comment: Definitely split services into separate repositories when possible. Then you put the deployment stuff in a separate repos as well that uses the built versions of the images from your image repository. It's so much cleaner.

Comment: ... at least when you work with more than a couple of people. I also don't want to see commits about configuration files for live mixed in with the apps.

Comment: Splitting services up in the separate repositories is a good idea and inline with the concept of microservices and the 12 Factor app recommendations. This is where Helm is a good candidate for future success with the emergence of repositories for hosting helm charts. Should make the deployment of complex eco-systems of micro services more palatible

Answer (score 5):

There's no good answer to this question currently.

Kubernetes provides a standard API for deployment, but as a technology it relies on additional 3rd party tooling manage the build part of the ALM workflow. There a lots of options available for turning your source code into a container running on Kubernetes. Each has it's own consequences for how your source code is organised and how a deployment might be invoked from a CI/CD server like Jenkins.

I provide the following collection of options for your consideration, roughly categorized. Represents my current evaluation list.

### "Platform as a service" tools

Tooling the manages the entire ALM lifecycle of your code. Powerful but more complex and opinionated.

- [Deis workflow](https://deis.com/workflow/)
- [Openshift](https://www.openshift.org/)
- [Fabric8 (See also Openshift.io)](https://fabric8.io/)

### Build and deploy tools

Tools useful for the code/test/code/retest workflow common during development. Can also be invoked from Jenkins to abstract your build process.

- [Draft](https://github.com/Azure/draft)
- [Forge](http://forge.sh/)
- [Kcompose](http://kompose.io/)
- [Fabric8 Maven plugin (Java)](https://maven.fabric8.io/)
- [Psykube](https://github.com/commercialtribe/psykube)

### YAML templating tools

The kubernetes YAML was never designed to be used by human beings. Several initatives to make this process simpler and more standardized.

- [Helm](https://helm.sh/)
- [Ksonnet](http://ksonnet.heptio.com/)

### Deployment monitoring tools

These tools have conventions where they expect to find Kubernetes manifest files (or helm charts) located in your source code repository.

- [Keel](https://keel.sh/)
- [Kube-applier](https://github.com/box/kube-applier)
- [Kubediff](https://github.com/weaveworks/kubediff)
- [Landscaper](https://github.com/Eneco/landscaper)
- [Kit](https://invisionapp.github.io/kit/)

### CI/CD tools with k8s support

- [Spinnaker](https://www.spinnaker.io/)
- [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/)
- [Jenkins + Kubernetes CI plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-ci)
- [Jenkins + Kubernetes plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Kubernetes+Plugin)